# How to check regex match in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having trouble with regex checking in javascript. I want when the user inputs in something to the text field my function should `alert` 'matched' or 'no match' according the regex in my code below. Please help

```js
function chech_password() {
  var str = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  var patt = new RegExp("^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$");
  var ress = patt.test(str);

  if (ress != true) {
    //$('#error_pass').html("wrong pasmatch");
    //$('#error_pass').show();
    //error_pass = true; 
    alert("no match");
  } else {
    //$('#error_pass').hide(); 
    alert("match");
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you have now should work fine, you just need to call `chech_password()` when required.

Comment: `if (!ress) {` would read slightly better :)

Comment: its working but its alerting the same message even i change my input values i get alert("no match");

Comment: Are you sure that your input element includes `id="pass"` and not just `name="pass"`? I would suggest setting a breakpoint on your function and checking to see what `str` and `ress` are being set to. Like the others said, the javascript function **looks** alright.